# Obtain element from array of list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

On my code, i've got an array of lists:

```
   public class xmldatalist
    {
        public List<xmldata>[] XMLArrayList = new List<xmldata>[9999];
    }
```

Each position on the list, contains a xmldata object (this class):

```
   public class xmldata //Class to receive items list
    {
        public string xml_filename { get; set; }
        public string colorname { get; set; }
        public string colorvalues { get; set; }

    }
```

Inside another method, i've got an loop to walk trough the non empty positions on this array of lists:

```
for(int n=0; n< GlobalVars.nonemptypos; n++)
            {
}
```

Inside this loop, i would like to retrieve the current xml_filename being processed.
i.e: Position 0 of the list has a xml_filename called bla1.bla - i would like to retrieve this name.

I've tried a LINQ Approach:

```
string name = XMLList.XMLArrayList[n].Select(x => x.xml_filename);

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'
```

What i'm trying to achieve is obtain the current xml_filename on n(indexer) position.

I've made some research but everywhere talks about ArrayList() , not array of lists.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear why you have an **array** of lists. Why not simply have a list of `xmldata`?

Comment: "Inside this loop, i would like to retrieve the current xml_filename being processed" -- so there's *another* for loop that's iterating through the list? As in, you showed us the for loop iterating through the array, and inside the `for(int n=0; n< GlobalVars.nonemptypos; n++)` there's another for loop, `foreach (var thing in XMLArrayList[n])`?

Comment: string name = XMLList.XMLArrayList[n].Select(x => x.xml_filename).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @NateBarbettini just a list of xmldata was giving too much trouble to be indexed later. Having an array of lists, i can have each position with specific attributes for each file.

Comment: @Gusman it did the trick. Its because on each iteration i'll have a different filename (and i pass it as argument to XmlWriter.Create). Worked as expected. About having another loop inside thats the idea - but i'll figure out how to iterate over it later. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
XMLList.XMLArrayList[n].Select(x => x.xml_filename)
```

is IEnumerable of strings, if you want to get the first string of them:

```
XMLList.XMLArrayList[n].Select(x => x.xml_filename).First()
```

Comment: Gusman did the trick on the comment. The trick was: string name = XMLList.XMLArrayList[n].Select(x => x.xml_filename).FirstOrDefault() - this returns me the filename being processed on each loop iteration. Thanks for your attention